# Rendering section script in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am suffering from these problem all day and I can't figure out what's going wrong
I have these code in my Events/Create view

```
@model UpdatedForum.Models.Event
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Events", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Event</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="imageinput" id="someid" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Description);
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Content/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['Description'];
        if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
        CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        });
        CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckfinder")');
    </script>
   }
```

The code for my _Layout.cshtml view is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CNET Forum</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/production/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/production/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/production/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
    <link href="~/Content/production/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/production/css/icheck/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Content/production/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div class="row">
          @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="~/Content/production/js/progressbar/bootstrap-         progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/production/js/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>



    <!-- icheck -->

    <script src="~/Content/production/js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Content/production/js/custom.js"></script>

    <!-- pace -->

    <script src="~/Content/production/js/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The error I am getting is

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC7MV.png)

Server Error in '/' Application.

The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "scripts".

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "scripts".

Comment: You view has `@section scripts`but your layout does not have `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Comment: I got it Thanks so much That was a great help.It fully works.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I have got the solution for it.Thanks for the suggestion.